# The correct way to perform signal processing on S-parameter data

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, continuous-signals, filtering, ifft

I have a question to ask you which has been bugging me as of late.

I have s-parameter data with 5001 samples acquired from a vector network analyzer. I am trying to 'gate' this s parameter data, i.e. take IFFT of the data, get a time vector, select a time range I want to keep, and nullify everything else.

As per the comments suggest, here is the specific input touchstone file data: Magnitude/Angle form, 1MHz - 40GHz.

Problem: When taking FFT of 'gated' data, I expect to see the same frequency pattern as the initial data, but with a much lower magnitude at the frequencies which correspond to the nullified time-domain data, such as below :

[image: Fig. 1, Time-domain gating (right), frequency domain result (left)]

Instead I get something like this :

[image: Fig. 2, Time domain gating (left), frequency domain result(right)]

As you can see, the 40 dB signal at the starting frequency should actually occur at around 4 GHz as per the frequency content of Fig. 1. Also, the S21 data in the frequency domain should be sloping upwards as the frequency increases.

Here is the original unfiltered time domain data for reference:

[image]

As I explained above, taking only a chunk of this time-domain data and taking it's FFT does not directly reproduce the same "chunk" of the frequency-domain data.

Comment: It would help if you could label your axis properly with real units. What exactly is your input data: magnitude and phase at what frequencies ?

Comment: Can you arrange the lower plots the same as your upper plots of the “good” example and include the before and after just as you did in the good example?

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I apologize for my late response, I have been dealing with some exams. I tried updating to the best of my ability. Mr. Boschen,  I am having a weird Python issue trying to plot data from Scikit-RF and Numpy on the same plot, so I provided you with a separate plot in the interest of time.